# How to redefine "word" in NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Text:

> 【233 24444 2223】【233 24444 2223】【233 24444 2223】【233 24444 2223]

I want to break the text in a UILabel

From:

> 【233 24444 2223】【233 24444 2223】【233
>   24444 2223】【233 24444 2223】

To:

> 【233 24444 2223】【233 24444 2223]
>   【233 24444 2223】【233 24444 2223】

In another word,I want to tell the UIlabel that the text inside `【】`is a word. So I can use NSlineBreakByWordWrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can replace the spaces in your UILabel for [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Breaking_and_non-breaking_spaces). For example:

```
label.text = @"Hello,\u00a0world!";
```